# Do I need a debit card if I already have a credit card?

Tags: united-states, credit-card, debit-card

As far as I've read, a credit card is generally better than a debit card. (Please correct me if I'm wrong.)

My question is should I *also* have a debit card? The downside is the added risk of the debit card getting lost or stolen.

Comment: @PeteB. have a debit card?

Comment: Some places (e.g. Costco in the UK) will take debit cards but not credit cards, due to the lower processing costs that they pay.

Comment: To be clear, I have a CC, but will not have a debit card.

Comment: Also WinCo (grocery chain in western US) only takes debit, also I think most Arco gas stations...  But all of them take cash :)

Comment: if you have checking account then you have debit card

Comment: Well it's always a good idea to have more than one card anyway. If you lose your only card you're SOL but if you have a debit card at least you have that.

Comment: @Alexan: Not necessarily.  For at least some accounts, the debit card is a separate feature that must be requested. (In the US: other countries' practices may differ, of course.)

Comment: @Azor-Ahai Even if you don't lose the card, you may find that for some reason one of them isn't working but the other is.  I've had a few situations like that when I was glad to have the debit card, even though I normally don't use it due to the superior protection provided by credit cards.

Comment: @MontyHarder For sure. It was just an illustration for the OP

Comment: Some vendors (ARCO) accept debit but not credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Some vendors, specifically utilities and rent payments, often will not accept credits cards for payments. While these can generally be managed through bank drafts instead, hiccups in payment systems happen, requiring alternative payment methods. This is where the debit card comes in handy.

2) Unless you are paying off your credit card every month, you are paying high fees on it. If debt is an issue, possessing a credit card can lead to greater debt issues over time.

3) Nearly every credit card I know of charges high fees for cash advances.  Mine is 17% if I remember correctly (I never use it). Without a debit card, you either pay expensive advance fees, or have to go to the bank. Debit cards allow withdrawals without exorbitant fees (couple of dollars for out if network transactions usually). And for many banks, they have an "in network" atm system without fees.

Answer (score 17):

Two issues I see with your question:

1. The word "need" is absolute.
2. It confuses the purpose of debit and credit cards.

Thus...

1. No, you don't *need* a debit card.  But it's a handy way to access your checking account (though obsoleted by smartphone bank apps), and get dead presidents without cashing a check.
2. Debit cards are instant access to your checking (and maybe savings) account, whereas credit cards are *loans*.  One good reason to have a DC instead of a CC is if you don't trust yourself to be disciplined with a CC, whereas you can (theoretically) only spend what you have using a DC.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My takeaway is that if one limits their spending, a DC boils down to cash withdrawal.

Comment: If you've got a smartphone bank app, and are disciplined, then.. correct.  I see no *need* for a DC.  @MikeScott makes a good point about maybe some stores accepting DC but not CC.  I've never seen it, but then there's a lot I haven't seen.

Comment: I'm assuming you get your "dead presidents" at an ATM?  You don't need a debit card for that, just an ATM card.  Of course you could have the same card being both (at least with my credit union) by activating the feature, but I've never seen the point of a debit card.  As for smartphone apps... well, that requires one to own and carry around a smart phone.

Comment: @jamesqf do literal *ATM* cards (say "ATM" on them, and work nowhere but ATMs) still exist?

Comment: @RonJohn: Mine doesn't say "ATM" on it ("Visa Gold Check Card"), and all it does for me is be an ATM card.  Sure, it could be a debit card, if I asked my credit union for that feature, but I don't want it.  As I said, I don't see the point: most places I could use a debit card, I can use a credit card and get 1-5% cash back, plus a month or so to pay.  The rest take cash, which is accepted even by those who don't take cards.

Comment: @jamesqf, if it has a VISA logo on it, it can be used anywhere Visa is accepted, right?  I didn't think a bank could selectively disable that.  If you try to use it right now, is it just declined?

Comment: @JPhi1618 VISA is just the network handling the transaction.  It could still be either a debit card or a credit card.  Old school ATM cards did not go via the VISA network.  They use a cheaper ATM only clearing/transaction network.

Comment: @Ukko, Right, I know that, but he's acting like his card is _only_ an ATM card that can't be used for debit transactions at a store that takes Visa.

Comment: @RonJohn Where I live in western US, there is a large chain of grocery stores that only accepts DC, cash, or (gasp) checks. It's a big cost cutting scheme that is supposed to be passed along to the consumer. If you don't accept CCs, you don't have to pay their fees and you can charge less for your goods.

Comment: It would be responsible to mention somewhere the differences in protection against liability from theft of the card/access to the account by ill-doers, although that might be country-specific. Someone who has your DC can wipe out your entire account; someone who has your CC can ring up a high debt, but the consumer is liable for only a portion ($50?) of that, and the bank eats the rest.

Comment: @TBear good to know.  ISTR that stores are allowed to pass on card fees.  https://www.creditcards.com/credit-card-news/business-surcharge-card-customers-1585.php

Comment: "though obsoleted by smartphone bank apps"  Nope.  I think there are like two stores, RiteAid and Starbucks, that let you pay with ApplePay/AndroidPay.  Visa check card though is almost universally accepted though.

Comment: @Andy by "obsoleted by smartphone bank apps", I meant access to things like your account balance and recent transactions.

Comment: Account balance and recent transactions don't seem to be relevant to what the OP is asking though, since he's comparing debit to credit cards.

Comment: @JPhi1618 the simple answer: yes, I have an ATM only card which says ATM on it. It only works at ATMs, and has a shorter expiry date. I chose this over a debit card.

Comment: @Andy yes, and with a debit card and an ATM, one can check ones balance. In addition (I don’t know where you live) most major stores in the UK accept Apple Pay. Anywhere with contactless support offers it (including Tesco, Sainsbury’s, Co-op, Lidl, Subway, Dominos, Costa, Wilko, Superdrug, Boots, The Post Office... the list goes on). I’ve not needed to type my PIN number in months.

Comment: @Tim Hardly worth getting a debit card for that reason.  Technically true but not worth mentioning; it seems pretty clear to me the OP is asking why should he get a debit card when credit cards offer more protection **for purchases**.  I don't think he's asking for a blanket "what is everything I can do with a debit card."

Comment: @Andy the OP doesn’t once mention purchases. I think giving every advantage of debit cards is exactly the right way to comprehensively answer the question “Do I need a debit card if I already have a credit card?”

Comment: @RonJohn ATM-only cards do still exist, though they aren't that common. I have one for an old HSBC savings account, which I'll sometimes use when traveling due to their large international presence. It does not work over the debit network; ATMs only.

Comment: @Andy he's asking why he'd need a DC, and "checking account balances and recent transaction" **is** a function of debit cards.

Comment: @JPhi1618: Re "If it says Visa on it..." I admit that I don't actually know whether or not it can be used as a debit card, never having had the inclination to try.  All I know is that the credit union quite regularly sends me junk mail offering to turn on the debit card feature, which leads me to assume that it's off by default.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71164/discussion-on-answer-by-ronjohn-do-i-need-a-debit-card-if-i-already-have-a-credi).

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen a place that takes debit but not credit cards.  Additionally, your bank may provide an ATM-only card that *cannot* be used as a debit card, but you have to ask explicitly for such an card without the debit feature.